# Java network communication problem

Tags: java, networking

I have a problem that I think might be a java related one.
I have a java application I need to emulate multiple hosts.

The server/client work fine between "normal" computers.

When I use the emulator, I get connection refused when client tries to connect to a server in the emulator, same thing if I try telnet.
If I turn it around, the client cannot connect to the external server, but if I telnet from the external server, I get a connection.

This makes me think it is a java related problem.

Anybody gone through this problem before? This is for research purposes, so turning off java security only for this situation is no problem.

Thanks!

Comment: If you telnet to the server from the machine you are running the emulator on what happens ? Native telnet from command line pls. Also can you post your stacktrace and error you are getting ? Please edit your original question with the answers

Comment: I don't follow your question, but for applets and WebStart, "untrusted" code is given permissions to resolve, connect (make an outgoing connection) and accept (receive an incoming connection) only from the "same-origin" host.

Answer (score 0):

When you say emulator, I think you are talking about a virtual machine. Connecting from the real world into a virtual machine is not something that works automatically. The virtual machine can initiate connections out because the virtualization software handles that. Going the other way - what machine name do you use. How you configure your physical machine to routce packets to the ip address of your virtual machine (which your virtualization software made up). You may need a proxy on your physical machine to route the packets into the virtual one.